# Passing bytes into proxy contract instead of bytes calldata

Tags: solidity

It's possible to pass bytes memory data instead of bytes calldata data into a proxy contract?

```
function callProxy(bytes memory _data, uint256 _value) private {
    (bool success, ) = proxyContract.call{ value: _value }(_data);
}
```

vs.

```
function callProxy(bytes calldata _data, uint256 _value) private {
    (bool success, ) = proxyContract.call{ value: _value }(_data);
}
```

Comment: Isn't calldata only for external functions? Yours is private.

Comment: I am quite new to solidity, but does the proxyContract count as an external functions? Would this work? The truffle.js compiler doesn't throw error :)

Comment: CALL opcode only accepts a memory pointer, so even if solidity accepts a calldata parameter it will copy it to a memory buffer before making the call.